# Why a process need a resource being held by another process in an operating system

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

2 Questions that need answering:

1) Why a process need a resource being held by another process in an operating system?

2) Following up to question #1: Why not avoid the deadlock problem altogether by putting the resources exactly in the same place as the process so there is no idea of "sharing" or "distribution" of resources among processes?

So the question relates to a deadlock concept where the process needs a resource from another process.

Comment: Think about what is meant by a "resource".  Do your question make sense in light of that?

Comment: What?   If there is only one resource, and it can only be sanely used by one process/thread at a time, and another process/thread is using it, you cannot have it until the other thread/process has released it. That is not deadlock, just resource management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A process may want to print on a printer but that printer may already been printing data of another process. Or it may want to read keys from a keyboard that another process is already reading.
2. As seen in 1, resources need to be shared to utilize them effectively. You can of course have one keyboard for each process and one printer for each document but that would be very costly.